# jsonpickle returns False on check instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsonpickle

I wonder why the jsonpickle-module when consecutively applying or calling **encode & decode** does not pass the **isinstance(...)** check in Python 3.8.

Let say i have a simple class **Person**.

Here some code to illustrate what i mean:

```
import jsonpickle


class Person:
    id: int = -1
    name: str = "John Doe"

    def __init__(self, pId: int = None, name: str = None) -> None:
        self.id = (pId, self.id)[pId is None]
        self.name = (name, self.name)[name is None]


testInstance = Person()
testInstanceJSON = jsonpickle.encode(testInstance, unpicklable=True, make_refs=True)
print(testInstanceJSON)
testInstanceObject = jsonpickle.decode(testInstanceJSON)
print(testInstanceObject)
print(isinstance(testInstanceObject, Person.__class__))
```

It returns **False** on the last print-command!

Comment: You test if it is of the same (or derived) class as the **class of Person** but the class of a class is "type".

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for replying, but how to make it pass the isinstance(...) check, what should i do ?  Or can i just use `print(type(testInstanceObject) == Person.__class__)`, it,s that what you exactly mean ?

Comment: Remove the `.__class__`. `Person` is already the class which "testInstanceObject" should be an instance of.

Comment: Right i got it  `print(isinstance(testInstanceObject, Person))` returns `True` as expected.
`

Comment: Make sure to write an answer, so i can mark it accordently @MichaelButscher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `__class__` of an object provides the class the object is an instance of.

Classes like `Person` are also objects and instances of `type`.

This means that

```
isinstance(testInstanceObject, Person.__class__)
```

is the same as

```
isinstance(testInstanceObject, type)
```

but of course `testInstanceObject` is not an instance of `type`.

Change it to

```
isinstance(testInstanceObject, Person)
```

to check if `testInstanceObject` is an instance of `Person`.